# How to update 7-Zip on Ubuntu

Tags: 7zip

[image: My version of 7-Zip]

The version of my 7-Zip on my Ubuntu is 16.02. However, this is not the newest version by far. Calling `sudo apt-get update` or `sudo apt-get upgrade` doesn't help. Is it just that the 7-Zip package is not maintained, or can I have up-to-date 7-Zip on my system?

EDIT: My version of Ubuntu is 18.10

Comment: Why do you think it's not the latest?  You didn't provide your release of Ubuntu, but packages available are https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=7zip, the upstream version is https://packages.debian.org/unstable/utils/p7zip & there is no later releases available on sourceforge http://p7zip.sourceforge.net/

Comment: In the meantime, [7-Zip has released v21.07 in Dec 2021](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check on https://sourceforge.net/projects/p7zip/files/p7zip/, you can see the latest version available is `16.02`, this also true per [Disco (19.04)](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=p7zip&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) releases.

The 'newest' version however, only available in Windows machine.

[image]

So it appear the developer of 7-Zip hasn't released latest version for Ubuntu yet, and considering it's been 3 years already, I don't think that will the case.

Comment: That's what I thought, but just wanted to make sure. Thanks